# How to change IP address dynamically?

Tags: python, selenium, ip

I am using python3 and selenium chromedriver on a windows pc. When I webscrape my IP address gets blocked sometimes. So my Question is how do I Change it dynamically or how do I hide it?

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! Add your code here so that community can better help you with your query. Add what you have done till now and where is the code you find the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use VPN, for example check out [vpngate.py](https://gist.github.com/Lazza/bbc15561b65c16db8ca8), you need to provide the desired output country:

```
vpngate.py US
```

I hope you get the idea, more information at the link.

Comment: But if I use VPN does the Website I am on see my IP

Comment: If you are entering a website behind VPN it won't see your original IP, just the one you got from the VPN.

Comment: So if I add "vpngate.py US" to my python Code it will not see my real IP?

Comment: Correct, it should see an IP from the country you set.